# recursive function and a breakpoint using F#

Tags: debugging, recursion, f#, breakpoints

Consider the following code:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args: string []) = 

  let rec main time =
    let newTime = time + 2 // place a breakpoint at this line
    main newTime

  main 0
```

I am not able to place a breakpoint at the marked line. I meet such problems quite often when using recursive functions and it really makes me not to use them. Is there any simple solution for that?

EDIT: I create a brand new solution and my build command looks like:

> '------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication4, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\x86\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- --platform:x86 -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Numerics.dll" --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors "C:\Users\olsv\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.fs" Program.fs 
>           ConsoleApplication4 -> d:\olsv\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped =========='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like, that it is a bug. I have already reported it to the F# team. So lets hope that they will fix it soon!

Answer (score 4):

I tried debugging the code you posted and it seems to be working just fine (I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1). When I place the breakpoint and run the code (as a console application) it stops at the breakpoint repeatedly and I can step to the next expression and see the state of local variables.

You could try checking compiler flags - the debugging works the best when you disable optimizations and tail-calls (this may be particularly relevant to recursive functions). When I build the project, the flags include the following:`--debug:full --optimize- --tailcalls-`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Take a look at the edit of my post. Do you see anything which could cause it? I also tried to import the default F# environment settings, yet without any luck. I use Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Comment: @OldrichSvec Hmm - That looks exactly the same as the build output I was getting. Does it change when you move the recursive `main` function from the non-recursive `main` function? (i.e. make it non-nested function). This looks like the only tricky thing about your sample...

Comment: I have simplified the code even further (see main post). I still observe the problem with that example. If I move the rec main out of the non rec main, the debugging works as expected. I would however like to  use nested rec functions and the debugging does not work for these. My VS2010 installation is 1.5 year old with regular updates only. May it be caused by an old F# version? How do I install a new version of F# into VS2010 SP1?

Comment: Visual Studio updates F# version for you, you cannot fully change it (believe me, we tried). If you have SP1 with latest updates - you have latest F#.